# svd adds value before an elastic net model?

Tags: svd, elastic-net

I learned that SVD eliminates redundancies. If you use an elastic net model, is it still greedy as stepwise models in general? or the fact that it has penalization factors reduces the greedy component?

If you are trying to predict  a continuous number and the predictors are words and their frequencies in each document, would it be a good idea to use first SVD and then something like the elastic net model?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elastic net is not greedy like stepwise model, it considers all variables together and shrinks their effects, sometimes to zero (depending on the penalty). In other words, the stepwise can depend heavily on the order in which you do the selection, but elastic-net does not (up to numerical issues which are unavoidable) [Note that lasso also depends to some extent on the order, but not as badly as stepwise]. So general advice is that it's best to avoid stepwise.

Regarding SVD (you really mean PCA I guess), then it depends on how many variables and samples you have. Doing dimensionality reduction will always remove information from your data, by definition, but in some cases that reduction may be offset by being able to better model the reduced data than the original data. So it's a case of trying out and seeing if it works. You do lose the interpretability since your new variables are now linear combinations of your original variables.

PCA is one way to decompose your data, but since it's frequencies which are non-negative numbers you might want to try out other decompositions like non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) that impose such constraints.

Comment: Thanks! really I meant LSI since my variables are words, the cases are documents and the values are the frequencies those words appears in each document.

Comment: But in this case the elastic net itself does the reduction, doesn't it? And since it's not greedy, how is it possible that a reduction method would add some value to the model?

Comment: Both. The PCA (LSI I assume too, not familiar with that) reduces your data from documents by words to documents by principal components where the number of principal components is less than the number of words (or <#documents, if there's fewer docs than words). Then on top of that, elastic-net can be used to further select principal components that contribute to the actual prediction task. When I talk about greedy, I refer to the way the algorithm selects which variables should enter the model; greedy means "select next strongest one", leading to instabilities depending on order of evaluation.

Comment: Dimensionality reduction using tranctuated svd (or pca if you don't care about the intercept) does NOT lose interpretability. You can always transform it back to the original axis. You do lose information from the dimensionality reduction but not interpretability.